# Onomatopoeia: Wind

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find Onomatopoeia words that sound like the wind. I have seen "howling" used to describe the sound. But, the closest Onomatopoeia word has been "whoosh."

What are other words that I can use?

Comment: Ftrom [etymonline,](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rustle) **rustle** (v.) *"to emit soft, rapid sounds," late 14c. (implied in rustling), of uncertain origin, **perhaps imitative**.* You need to specify both *what kind of wind* (breeze, hurricane, etc.) and *what exactly you mean by "onomatopoeic"*.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Dan, Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
answer,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions.

Comment: @MetaEd: I think you're sometimes overzealous about deleting my comments. Obviously I wasn't ***answering*** the question - I was ***explaining my closevote***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Looked like some of both to me. Sorry I overstepped. Here's your comment back.

Comment: @MetaEd: I can't swear to it, but my recollection is I was *originally* going to VTC as POB (same as you), but when I found "perhaps imitative" in the etymology of ***rustle***, I switched to "Unclear" - because that immediately raised two completely separate issues, each of which could have significant implications for whether or not any given suggestion in any specific "Answer" might be something we could all agree stood out as the best/right term. Note that I absolutely agree your first comment to the only answer here, but that doesn't imply the question couldn't have been more "focused".

Answer (score 1):

A collection of a few: swish, swoosh, whiff, whoosh, whizz, and whisper

(Taken from [here](https://literarydevices.net/onomatopoeia/))

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MetaEd: I'm not sure how the given answer fails to meet those criteria. It gives the answer to the question (what are some onomatopoetic words for wind sound?) with a cited source as support. Could you suggest an edit to improve the answer so I'll know what you're looking for?

Comment: I agree with @L. Scott Johnson. I've edited my question to include "What are other words that I can use?"

Comment: Good question. When answering, bear in mind that you should be offering, not ideas or multiple answers, but *the* right answer, as you see it. When you find that multiple answers seem to be in order, then the problem is that the question is unclear or it is asking for items or ideas. This is the point at which you would go back and ask for clarification.